# How can I perform a full-text CONTAINS call across a list of phrases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, full-text-search

I have a list of words/phrases in a table `phrases`. I have another table with a full-text catalog indexing the `description` column.

I want to populate a table `results` with a record for each phrase, and the number of times that phrases was found in the description:

```
INSERT INTO results(phrase, foundcount)
SELECT  phrase, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE CONTAINS(table.description, phrase))
FROM    phrases;
```

No matter how I try, this results in the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near `phrase`. Expecting STRING, TEX_LEX, or VARIABLE
```

I would really rather not use a cursor just so I can assign each `phrase` to a variable. Is that really the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
go
create function dbo.fn_GetCountForPhrase (@phrase varchar(500))
    returns  int
as
begin
    declare @count int
    declare @localphrase varchar(8000)
    set @localphrase='"' + @phrase + '"'
    SELECT @count=COUNT(*) FROM table  a WHERE CONTAINS(table.description,   @localphrase)
    return @count
end
go
SELECT  
    phrase,  
    dbo.fn_GetCountForPhrase(phrase) 
FROM phrases
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can get what you need from the DMVs, including `sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document` and `sys.dm_fts_parser`, something like this:

```
SELECT p.phrase, kbd.display_term
FROM sys.dm_fts_index_keywords_by_document( DB_ID(), OBJECT_ID('dbo.documentText') ) kbd
    CROSS APPLY dbo.phrases p
        CROSS APPLY sys.dm_fts_parser  ( N'FORMSOF(FREETEXT, "' + phrase + N'")', 1033, 0, 1 ) x
WHERE x.display_term = kbd.display_term
```

Caution: if you wrap your searches in quotes you get an exact match, so you're not really getting the benefit of full-text indexing.  You could also just do that with `Like` and wildcards(`%`).  Also scalar functions do not tend to scale well over large resultsets.